# geom_violin() - figure border is curved in a strange way

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm investigating data with smooth and almost convex distribution of integer values. But when I print it with `geom_violin()` I got strange shape like there are very rare intermediate non-integer values. How to avoid these "bottlenecks" on the plot near `y = 1.5` & `y = 2.5` and what do they mean?

```
require( ggplot2)
df <- data.frame( x = 1, y = c( rep( 1, 100), rep( 2, 25), rep( 3, 5)))
ggplot( data = df, aes( x, y)) + geom_violin( )
```

[image: distribution bottlenecks plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* what you're objecting to is the over-smoothing (for your purposes) of the distribution.  If you like you can play with the `adjust` parameter, which is an argument to the `density` function:

> adjust: the bandwidth used is actually ‘adjust*bw’.  This makes it easy to specify values like ‘half the default’ bandwidth.

So to make the violin plot less smooth/more faithful to the data (at the cost of including more noisy wiggles as well), reduce `adjust`:

```
require( ggplot2)
df <- data.frame( x = 1, y = c( rep( 1, 100), rep( 2, 25), rep( 3, 5)))
ggplot( data = df, aes( x, y)) + geom_violin(adjust=0.1)
```